# What is the infinite sum of $a^{b^x}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, summation, exponential-sum

What would $$\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}(1/2)^{4^n}$$ be and how to determine it?

Note that is not a typo, it is of the form $a^{b^x}$ if it were $(1/2)^{4n}$ it would of course be trivial and could be treated using the geometric series summation formula $1/(1-r)$ with $r$ being $1/16$.

---

I can see this converges by the ratio test. My issue is working out its sum, more for fun really.

It expands to $(1/2) + (1/2)^{4} + (1/2)^{4^2} + \ldots + (1/2)^{4^n}$, and
there doesn't seem to be anything simple to do. I have attempted to look for analogies by treating it as a function and integrating, but it doesn't seem expressible with elementary functions.

Is this a problem that cannot be tackled by elementary methods, (the only methods I currently have at my disposal)?
What things should I study to be able to handle these kind of sums?

Comment: Is it $i$ or $n$?

Comment: Please give some context on where this question comes from and what do you already know/your thoughts on the problem

Comment: And are you sure it's about $(\frac12)^{4^n}$ or rather $((\frac12)^4)^n$?

Comment: Do you actually have to determine it or check if it converges? The latter is trivial as $\sum_i (1/2)^i$ converges.

Comment: Both wolfram alpha and sagemath is unable to find a closed form solution, so I doubt one exists.

Comment: It definitely converges though

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Hopefully my edits have clarified my question

Comment: This is an example of a lacunary series; I learned a bit about them upon asking a question at [here at MSE](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/887671/137524) and another at [MathOverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/q/178549/55904). Both of those question threads have some useful discussion and links to literature. One thing I can immediately say based on what I learned there: since $1/2$ is algebraic, the series you propose is transcendental.

Comment: @Semiclassical great comment and posts. Really interesting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By asking what the infinite sum *is*, would you like to write it down as a decimal (using base 10)?

#### Review of decimals:

A decimal $.a_1a_2a_3...$ really is itself an infinite series:
$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{a_n}{10^{n}}$$

We are comfortable with such series at least partly because we know exactly how to interpret the accuracy of such an expression: If $a$ is the above decimal and we approximate it by using the first $n$ digits, then we are within $(.1)^{n}$ of the real value of $a$.

---

#### "Evaluating" the given series:

Even if there isn't a nice way to express your given series, all is not lost; we need only know how accurate given approximations are. In fact, we can compare the tail of the given series with a geometric series: for all $k>0$,
$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=k}(1/2)^{4^n} < \sum^{\infty}_{n=4^{k}}(1/2)^{n} = 2 \times (1/2)^{4^{k}}.$$

In other words, we have an upper bound on the error produced by the partial sum $\sum^{k-1}_{n=0}(1/2)^{4^n}$. And this upper bound approaches zero very very quickly: for $k = 5,$ we have the following inequality: $2 \times (1/2)^{4^{k}} < (.1)^{307}$. That means that if you evaluate $\sum^{4}_{n=0}(1/2)^{4^n}$, you will be accurate to more than 300 decimal places! It begins like this: $0.562515258789062$.

Finally, note that you are already given the **binary** expansion of this number by the series itself: $.10010000000000010000000000000001...$
(The set of indices where the $1$'s appear is $\{4^{n} | n = 0,1,2,...\}$.)

Comment: This should be CW.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer.